# How can I go about Parsing all values after a specfic bracked tag

Tags: c#, text-parsing

I have a text file structured As follows.

```
[email]
emailAddress
emailAddress
emailAddress

[somthingelse]
stuff
stuff
stuff
```

etc...

I have tried several regex, file reading, and stream reader methods with no luck

I need to get all values under each `[xxxx]` in to a list
example:

```
List<string> email = new List<string>();
```

Search file for `[email]` add the email address to the list.
continue reading for next `[smothingelse]` add the values to the something else list

etc...

Any help please

Comment: What have you written so far?

Comment: Just loop through each line, if it's [xxxx] you know you're about to start assigning the subsequent lines to a particular collection. Repeat. If you want a more detailed answer you need to post a more detailed question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here your solution :

```
Dictionary<string,List<string>> values = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

var lines = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt");
var reg = new Regex(@"^\[(\w+)\]$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
string lastMatch = "";

foreach (var ligne in lines.Where(a=>!String.IsNullOrEmpty(a)))
{
    var isMatch =  reg.Match(ligne);
    if (isMatch.Success)
    {
        lastMatch = isMatch.Groups[0].Value;
        if(!values.ContainsKey(lastMatch))
            values.Add(lastMatch,new List<string>());
    }else
        values[lastMatch].Add(ligne);
}
```

It will give you an Dictionary with all values for each tag, escaping empty lines, your file has to begin with a tag you mention.
Regex is just to detect [] presence and capture content. It will associate to the tag all the elements folowing the tag. until another tag is found.

Of course as you can see the result expected is contained in values variable.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  I did not think about using a Dictionary in this manor.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like .ini file. There are lot of c# libraries for parsing this. But assuming you want to do your own way:

```
foreach line in file:

    if line contains "[email]":
        _list_you_need  is "Email list"
        continue

    _list_you_need.push(line)
```

Comment: Even as pseudo-code, that's incorrect.

Comment: At least, you could explain why so the OP could understand

Comment: Well it's not even C#!?

Comment: User did not show any atempt of code. I gave him a bit of pseudo-code. Not the actual solution he wants.

Comment: `User did not show any atempt of code` ask him then. `Not the actual solution he wants.` so by your own admission it's not an answer.

Comment: It does what he wants, but he actually has to code. It is better than asking for code and it gives him a "solution" that he has to think how to implement it in c#. In your own perspective, i should give just the code or ask him for the solution.

Comment: You're not his teacher, though? If you feel the question lacks clarity or is too broad due to the lack of detail, flag the issue or vote to close it. Assuming he's new to C#, you just sent him something he may try to actually use before wondering why there are a ton of syntax errors.

Comment: It does not lack clarity or detail. I know what he wants to do. I prefer to give him a direction rather than the "copy paste" solution. The user points "I have tried several **regex, file reading, and stream reader methods with no luck"** so no.. he's not a beginner.

Comment: You're in the wrong place. This is not a site for providing guidance as an answer. A better form of 'guidance' would come as a comment, maybe asking the OP to break down his problem into more manageable tasks. Read a file, parse a line, how to iterate, if conditions.

Comment: So you know exactly what he wants to do but are choosing to tease him with pseudo code? This site is for specifics, for a few reasons. The question has been tagged with C#, specifically.

Comment: User asks for "Any help please" not for "Please give me code". This "place" what you call provides users  help to get their questions answered. If he had a question on how this c# code was doing something wrong, i would have pointed out what it was. Since it is not the case, i didn't. You win. We have different approaches in how to **help** users.

Answer (score -1):

With Linq

```
        var emailList = File.ReadLines(inputFile)
                        .SkipWhile(x => x != "[email]")
                        .Skip(1)
                        .TakeWhile(x => !x.StartsWith("["))
                        .Where(x=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Take a breath, longest sentence ever.

Comment: `SkipWhile(x => x == "[email]")` is incorrect

Comment: Right, only works if its at first line. I correct. Thanks